# Capitalize first letter in PHP using RegEx?

Tags: php, sorting

I have data in a notepad file as following:

```
A   1-6
A   1-7
B   1-8
B   1-9
B   1-10
c   1-11
C   1-12
D   1-13
F   1-14
F   1-15
f   1-16
```

I want above data to be updated as below in the notepad file:

```
<strong>A</strong>  1-6
A   1-7
<strong>B</strong>  1-8
B   1-9
B   1-10
<strong>c</strong>  1-11
C   1-12
<strong>D</strong>  1-13
<strong>F</strong>  1-14
F   1-15
f   1-16
```

Which means adding a `<strong>` tag or any other tag with first character alphabetically. The data in file is sorted alphabetically (A to Z).

I want to achieve this in PHP using RegEx techniques, please help!

Thanks.

Comment: I hope using regex is not obligatory?

Comment: I need its RegEx version as well, as I might have to use this with GREP routine.

Comment: Someone added an answer, but deleted it, I request please add it again, that will also helpful in achieving it in PHP.

Comment: Why do you want to add HTML to a file that otherwise is plain text? Also, the question title is misleading. You do not want to capitalize the content, but wrap it in markup. Strong tags do not capitalize. They add strong semantic emphasis to the wrapped content.

Comment: @Gordon, yes I want to add HTML tag, thought that can be different as well, I'll modify it as per my need, but for now I want to add a HTML tag around the first letter, as displayed in above output.

Comment: It would be difficult to use with 'grep' since it's line-based.  You could use 'awk' instead since you'd be able to keep track of the value of a column and only change the output when it's different than the past value of the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like :

```
$seen = array();
$file = array(
'A   1-6',
'A   1-7',
'B   1-8',
'B   1-9',
'B   1-10',
'c   1-11',
'C   1-12',
'D   1-13',
'F   1-14',
'F   1-15',
'f   1-16'
);
foreach($file as $line) {
    $L = strtoupper(substr($line, 0, 1));
    if (!isset($seen[$L])) {
        $line = preg_replace('!^(.)!', "<strong>$1</strong>", $line);
        $seen[$L] = 1;
    }
    echo $line,"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<strong>A</strong>   1-6
A   1-7
<strong>B</strong>   1-8
B   1-9
B   1-10
<strong>c</strong>   1-11
C   1-12
<strong>D</strong>   1-13
<strong>F</strong>   1-14
F   1-15
f   1-16
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `awk` instead of `grep` at the command line:

**example.file:**

```
A   1-6
A   1-7
B   1-8
B   1-9
B   1-10
c   1-11
C   1-12
D   1-13
F   1-14
F   1-15
f   1-16
```

**AWK (case-insensitive):**

```
cat example.file | awk 'BEGIN {last=""} {if (tolower($1) != last) printf "<b>"$1"</b>"; else printf $1; print " "$2;last=tolower($1)}'
```

**Output:**

```
<b>A</b> 1-6
A 1-7
<b>B</b> 1-8
B 1-9
B 1-10
<b>c</b> 1-11
C 1-12
<b>D</b> 1-13
<b>F</b> 1-14
F 1-15
f 1-16
```

With a minor tweak, you could also just avoid printing the redundant first column entirely and summarize all the data beneath the first occurrence:

```
cat t | awk 'BEGIN {last=""} {if (tolower($1) != last) print "<b>"$1"</b>"; print $2;last=tolower($1)}'
```

**Output:**

```
<b>A</b>
1-6
1-7
<b>B</b>
1-8
1-9
1-10
<b>c</b>
1-11
1-12
<b>D</b>
1-13
<b>F</b>
1-14
1-15
1-16
```

If this is truly HTML, you should probably also add in your `<BR>` tags.